# How to resolve timeout error in azurerm_backup_protected_vm?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm, terraform-template-file, hashicorp

I am trying to create **azurerm_backup_protected_vm** using terraform but getting timeout error while creating a resource, below is my terraform file.

***Terraform version - v0.13.3***

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "tfex-recovery_vault"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "example" {
  name                = "tfex-recovery-vault"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_backup_policy_vm" "example" {
  name                = "tfex-recovery-vault-policy"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.example.name

  backup {
    frequency = "Daily"
    time      = "23:00"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "vm_backup" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.example.name
  source_vm_id        = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  backup_policy_id    = azurerm_backup_policy_vm.example.id
}
```

when I run terraform apply command `resource group`, `recovery service vault`, `backup policy` is created successfully but getting below error while creating **azurerm_backup_protected_vm**

```
module.vm-linux.azurerm_backup_protected_vm.vm_backup: Still creating... [1h19m20s elapsed]
module.vm-linux.azurerm_backup_protected_vm.vm_backup: Still creating... [1h19m30s elapsed]
module.vm-linux.azurerm_backup_protected_vm.vm_backup: Still creating... [1h19m40s elapsed]
module.vm-linux.azurerm_backup_protected_vm.vm_backup: Still creating... [1h19m50s elapsed]
module.vm-linux.azurerm_backup_protected_vm.vm_backup: Still creating... [1h20m0s elapsed]

Error: Error waiting for the Azure Backup Protected VM "VM;iaasvmcontainerv2;PZI-GXU2-N-RGP-SB000-D065;U2ZSB000WDLV032" to be true (Resource Group "PZI-GXU2-N-RGP-SB000-D065") to provision: timeout while waiting for state to become 'Found' (last state: 'NotFound', timeout: 1h20m0s)

  on modules/vm-linux/main.tf line 76, in resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "vm_backup":
  76: resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "vm_backup" {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would like to suggest adding the [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/depends_on.html) Meta-Argument in the backup-related resources to make sure that the backup VM will be enabled after VM is provisioned.

```
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "example" {
 #..
 depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine.example]
}

resource "azurerm_backup_policy_vm" "example" {
 #..
  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine.example]

}

resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "vm_backup" {
  #..
  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_machine.example]

}
```

[Here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/4774#issuecomment-562144149) is a sample for more references.

```
# This resource is defined to fix the timeout problem in the creation of 'azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm.*' resources
resource "null_resource" "delay" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 180"
  }

  depends_on = [
    "azurerm_virtual_machine.portal",
    "azurerm_virtual_machine.engine",
    "azurerm_virtual_machine.gateway",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm" "portal" {
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.default.name}"
  recovery_vault_name = "${data.terraform_remote_state.shell.backup_vault_name}"
  source_vm_id        = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.portal.id}"
  backup_policy_id    = "${data.terraform_remote_state.shell.backup_policy_id}"

  depends_on = ["null_resource.delay"]
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm" "engine" {
  count               = "${var.number_of_engines}"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.default.name}"
  recovery_vault_name = "${data.terraform_remote_state.shell.backup_vault_name}"
  source_vm_id        = "${element(azurerm_virtual_machine.engine.*.id, count.index)}"
  backup_policy_id    = "${data.terraform_remote_state.shell.backup_policy_id}"

  depends_on = ["null_resource.delay"]
}

resource "azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm" "gateway" {
  count               = "${var.number_of_gateways}"
  resource_group_name = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.default.name}"
  recovery_vault_name = "${data.terraform_remote_state.shell.backup_vault_name}"
  source_vm_id        = "${element(azurerm_virtual_machine.gateway.*.id, count.index)}"
  backup_policy_id    = "${data.terraform_remote_state.shell.backup_policy_id}"

  depends_on = ["null_resource.delay"]
}
```